# Is there a function for which the sum converges while the limit diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, smooth-functions

Once I take my integral of f'(x) from n+1 to n I'll get f(n+1)-f(n). Since I already needed a function that's limit diverged, shouldn't my sum also diverge? This leads me to believe that this is a trick question and is impossible.

[image]

Comment: I immediately want to go for a periodic sine function with 'wavelength' 1, such that the integral of the derivative is always 0 but it diverges. :) $sin(2\pi x)$

Comment: If I were to solve and set up my sum for f(x)=2pix then I would still get a divergent sum using divergence test.

Comment: As you said, you're integral would be f(n+1) - f(n) but for all integers $\sin(2\pi x)$ is 0, so the sum from 1 to infinity of zero is still zero, but sine goes to zero.

Answer (score 2):

The upper expression simplifies to $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$.

So take $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$. 
$f(n) \equiv 0$ but $f(x)$ oscillates, so it is divergent.

Comment: how does the limit of f(n)= 0? Isn't sin(infinity) divergent?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0$, and the function evaluates to $0$ at every integer.  This solution is a function that is zero at every integer, but does not have a limit at infinity.